# looking for the NAME of a specific kind of concurrency problems

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

You have the following scenario:

```
//Two threads, using shared data

shared data = 2  
Thread1: reads shared data  
Thread2: reads shared data  
Thread1: shared data = read value + 1  
Thread2: shared data = read value + 1  

result: shared data = 3  
//Should have been 4 if not for this problem.
```

I don't want a solution for the problem, I know how to fix it and it is not relevant for the actual question.

I want the technical term for this specific kind of problem that comes with concurrency. Using it for a technical report.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't that simply known as a race condition?

Comment: thank you! That's what I'm looking for. I've had it on the tip of my brain so to speak for hours. So frustrating, it kept eluding me. Thanks.